# How to search for the next index in R

Tags: r

I have 2 DF's `DF_1` e `DF_2`:

```
DF_1 <- data.frame(
  REQUEST_DATE = c("01-01-2024", "02-01-2024","02-01-2024" ,"03-01-2024","04-01-2024","05-01-2024","06-01-2024","12-01-2024","15-01-2024"),
  REQUEST_TIME = c("05:23:52", "20:00:01", "22:30:39","15:15:32","17:10:17","07:00:12","11:22:00","18:52:00","08:44:19"))
DF_1$REQUEST_DATE <- as.Date(DF_1$REQUEST_DATE, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
DF_1$REQUEST_TIME <- format(DF_1$REQUEST_TIME, format = "%H:%M:%S")


DF_2 <- data.frame(
  DATE = c(seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-01-15"), by = "days")),
  USEFUL_DATE = c("NO","YES","YES","YES","YES","NO","NO","YES","YES","YES","YES","NO","NO","NO","YES"),
  NEXT_USEFUL_DATE = c("02-01-2024", "02-01-2024" ,"03-01-2024","04-01-2024","05-01-2024","08-01-2024","08-01-2024","08-01-2024","09-01-2024","10-01-2024","11-01-2024","15-01-2024","15-01-2024","15-01-2024","15-01-2024"))
DF_2$NEXT_USEFUL_DATE <- as.Date(DF_2$NEXT_USEFUL_DATE, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

I want to create a new variable in `DF_1` called `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL`, meeting the following conditional:

1. If `REQUEST_DAT`E is `USEFUL_DATE` equals “YES” and is between 07:00:00 and 19:00:00, then REQUEST_DATE_FINAL must concatenate `REQUEST_DATE` and `REQUEST_TIME`;
2. If `REQUEST_DATE` is `USEFUL_DATE` equals “YES” and is between 00:00:00 and 06:59:59, then `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL` must concatenate REQUEST_DATE and 07:00:00;
3. If `REQUEST_DATE` is `USEFUL_DATE` equals “NO”, then `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL` has to look in `USEFUL_DATE` for the next date equals “YES”. Example: if `REQUEST_DATE` equals 01/01/2024, the `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL` will be 02/01/2024 07:00:00.
4. If `REQUEST_DATE` is `USEFUL_DATE` equal to “`YES`” and is between 19:00:01 and 23:59:59, then `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL` must consider the immediately subsequent date as "`YES`" and concatenate REQUEST_DATE and 07:00:00. Example: if `REQUEST_DATE` is equal to 02/01/2024 and `REQUEST_TIME` is equal to 20:00:01, the `REQUEST_DATE_FINAL` will be 03/01/2024 07:00:00:

See how `DF_1` would look populated with these conditions being met:

```
DF_1 <- DF_1 %>% 
  mutate(REQUEST_DATE_FINAL = c("02/01/2024  07:00:00","03/01/2024  07:00:00","03/01/2024  07:00:00","03/01/2024  15:15:32","04/01/2024  17:10:17","05/01/2024  07:00:12", "08/01/2024  07:00:00","15/01/2024  07:00:00","15/01/2024  08:44:19"))
DF_1$REQUEST_DATE_FINAL <- as.POSIXlt(DF_1$REQUEST_DATE_FINAL, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

I don't know how to make this query checking in `DF_2`. I thought the solution could come from `case_when`, but it would be necessary to use "`for`", but I don't know how to use "`for`" yet. I imagine it would go through the immediately subsequent index search in `DF_2`.

Comment: Hi, there. Please have in mind that the answers provided should only respond to only one representative data. If you require help with a different dataset, consider ask a separate question and avoid constantly changing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table join operation is usually useful when you want to query from more than one table. Your intuition about `case_when` is correct, but there is not need for a manual `loop`.

```
#left join df2 to df1
DF_3 <- left_join(DF_1,DF_2, by=c('REQUEST_DATE'='DATE'))

#mutate according to your conditions
DF_3%>%
arrange(REQUEST_DATE)%>%
  mutate(REQUEST_DATE_FINAL = 
           ifelse(USEFUL_DATE=='NO', paste(as.character(NEXT_USEFUL_DATE), '07:00:00', ' '), 
                  case_when(as.numeric(str_match(REQUEST_TIME,pattern='\\d.')) >= 7 & as.numeric(str_match(REQUEST_TIME,pattern='\\d.')) <= 19 ~ paste(REQUEST_DATE, REQUEST_TIME, ' '), 
                            as.numeric(str_match(REQUEST_TIME,pattern='\\d.')) < 7  ~ paste(as.character(REQUEST_DATE), '07:00:00', ' '), 
                            as.numeric(str_match(REQUEST_TIME,pattern='\\d.')) > 19 ~ paste(as.character(lead(REQUEST_DATE)), '07:00:00', ' '))))

#results
  REQUEST_DATE REQUEST_TIME USEFUL_DATE NEXT_USEFUL_DATE    REQUEST_DATE_FINAL
1   2024-01-01     05:23:52          NO       2024-01-02 2024-01-02 07:00:00  
2   2024-01-02     20:00:01         YES       2024-01-02 2024-01-03 07:00:00  
3   2024-01-03     15:15:32         YES       2024-01-03 2024-01-03 15:15:32  
4   2024-01-04     17:10:17         YES       2024-01-04 2024-01-04 17:10:17  
5   2024-01-05     07:00:12         YES       2024-01-05 2024-01-05 07:00:12  
6   2024-01-06     11:22:00          NO       2024-01-08 2024-01-08 07:00:00  
7   2024-01-12     18:52:00          NO       2024-01-15 2024-01-15 07:00:00  
8   2024-01-15     08:44:19         SIM       2024-01-15 2024-01-15 08:44:19
```

Here I accommodated your typo "SIM", and you can remove it if it is not in your actual data.

Comment: Thanks @Jinjin. Unfortunately it is not correct. See line 2 (2024-01-02 20:00:01), the result should be 2024-01-03 07:00:00

Comment: @BrunoAvila Are you sure your expected results correctly match your conditions? line 2 (2024-01-02 20:00:01), have USEFUL_DATE ="Yes" and `NEXT_USEFUL_DATE` the same as `REQUEST_DATE`. Why would it use 2024-01-03? ps. your condition did not define the interval between 19:00:00 - 00:00:00, so I assume it is missing in condition 2. If it is something else, you should clearly describe it.

Comment: When the date is equal to "YES", but the time is between 19:00:00 and 23:59:59, you must check the next date with "YES", that is, 2024-01-03

Comment: I agree with you, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I will edit the post.

Comment: I added the item nº 4.

Comment: @BrunoAvila Good. I see. Just to confirm that "SIM" is considered as "YES", or anything else?

Comment: "SIM" is considered as "YES". I made a typing error.

Comment: Something strange, because in DF_3 it is not coming in the format 2024-01-03 07:00:00

Comment: @BrunoAvila Isn't "2024-01-03 07:00:00" what you want? Do you mean data type? You can convert it using `as.POSIXlt()`.

Comment: I discovered an inconsistency. If you have a record, for example, 2024-01-02 21:20:15, using "lead" will not work, as "lead" takes the next record.

Comment: @BrunoAvila I can't see any reason that "2024-01-02 21:20:15" or whatever else will not work, `lead()` will always take the next unless there is none (e.g. at the last position).

Comment: updated the code. Note that the use of "lead" brings an inconsistency. The results for lines 2 and 3 should come out as "2024-01-02 2024-01-03 07:00:00". See that using your code the result is 2024-01-02 2024-01-03 07:00:00 and 2024-01-03 2024-01-03 07:00:00 respectively.